# Oracle Loop through table until variable length is full

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a loop in Oracle using SQL Developer.

I am looping through a table and storing the content into a VarChar with 4000 characters.

When the total amount of value goes higher than 3500 I want to exit the loop and warn the user.

Below is my code that I have made so far....

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE
      comp_str varchar2(4000) := NULL;
      varlength varchar2(4000):= NULL;

      CURSOR C1 IS
        SELECT column1, column2, column3
        FROM table
        WHERE column1 = 'value';
    BEGIN
        FOR C1_REC IN C1
        Loop

        SELECT length(comp_str) into varlength FROM DUAL;                  

          if varlength < 3500 THEN         
            if comp_str is null then
                comp_str := c1_rec.string1 || ',' || c1_rec.string2;
            else              
                comp_str := comp_str || ' <br> ' || c1_rec.string1 || ',' || c1_rec.string2;
            end if;
            else

           comp_str := comp_str || '<br><br>End Of Limit ';
            EXIT ;
          end if; 
        End Loop;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: Why do you select values from columns like 'column1' and then refer to fields like 'string1'? You should use something like c1_rec.column1 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the type of varlength from varchar2 to number;

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `varlength` or your `select ... into`, remove them both.  Then just make your IF statement look like this...

`if comp_str is null or length(comp_str) < 3500 then`

Answer (score 0):

I found that this solution works best if anyone is interested:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE
      comp_str varchar2(4000) := NULL;
      MoreText varchar2(4000) := NULL;

      CURSOR C1 IS
        SELECT column1, column2, column3
        FROM table
        WHERE column1 = 'value';
    BEGIN
        FOR C1_REC IN C1
        Loop

          MoreText := c1_rec.string1 || ',' || c1_rec.string2 || '<br>';  

          If length(comp_str  || MoreText) < 3800 then
            comp_str := comp_str  || MoreText;
          else 
             comp_str := comp_str || '<p>End Of Limit></p>';
             EXIT ;
         end if;
        End Loop;
    END;
END;
```